# Backend for multiple instances of app

Tags: c#, android, ios, azure, backend

I'm building an app for a beautysalon, the app has a backend where an administrator can manage the content for the app. In example, news, treatment, pricelists.

Now I had the idea to use the backend for multiple instances of the same app. So beautysalon X uses this app but beautysalon Y also has the same app, with of course their own layout (logo, colours ect).

The backend is running on Azure, made with C#.

Now I can see me splitting the data, so that the beauty salons only see their own data. I think the biggest problem is push notifications, since you can only have one certificate.

I don't want to have a backend for every single app I sell.
How would you design an app and backend for this situation?

Thanks in advance, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating sub domain for each salon. Thus you need to use only one certificate. You could also use different database for different salons.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I'm not sure how this would work since you need certificates for each app. There will be one backend with multiple apps, technically one app but branded to the specific costumer (so a new registration in the app store). 

Can you have one App/Mobile Service with Multiple Notification Hubs? I think that is the biggest problem.

Comment: What you can do is, use same project number in each application. You could send custom generated app id with each notification. You can filter this id at mobile app. If it contains same app id then proceed or discard it. This should work with android app only.